# Is a rigid gazebo roof less likely to be damaged by wind than a fabric roof?

Tags: wood, deck

**Issue Summary**

- Had a fabric canopy topped gazebo.
- It was strapped to the railing and seemed very secure for 2 years.
- One very bad wind storm (like a parachute) it tore off the straps and flew into the yard.

I am going to buy a new one.  Is a hard-top canopy more or less likely to act like a sail in high winds?

Comment: What does "act like a sail" mean? Wind doesn't care what material it's running into. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @isherwood.  A sheet of plywood for a sail on a sailboat would not be very effective.  Therefore, what I am asking the community is if a rigid canopy would provide better resilience against potential harm during high winds as opposed to canvas which would billow, like a sail or parachute - lifting the gazebo up like what happened to my old one.

Comment: Plywood would make an excellent sail, discounting its weight. Since weight isn't a real factor in your situation, the question stands. What qualities of being sail-like are you asking about? Obviously plywood doesn't billow like fabric, so that leaves me scratching my head. Judging by the poor response you've received, I'm not alone. I've edited your post to ask just one question per [the network's guidelines](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Lee Sam's answer is good, but you can't apply it to any flexible and any rigid materials you might try.  There are rigid but flimsy materials, and flexible but strong materials.  There are some flexible materials that are likely to hold up better than some rigid materials.  There is also the variable of how they are fastened.  In addition, there are ways to make either one more windproof, such as the segmented design of windproof umbrellas.  To get a solid answer, you would need to be specific about the materials, how they would be fastened, and the design.

Comment: I bought a rigid gazebo and very happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structurally, the fabric will put more stress on your gazebo than a fixed panel for two reasons: 1) When the fabric “snaps” from the thrust of the wind, it creates an IMPACT load, and 2) A fixed (rigid) panel will DISTRIBUTE the load to other structural members.

Likewise, something that flexes and moves will tend to “wear” more than something that does not. Maintenance will be more in the long run.

For just simple enjoyment of the space, I’d think a rigid “roof” would be quieter too...best for conversations.